# Property 'utils' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/ethers")'

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I'm a noob so go easy on me haha
I am trying to use utils from ethers and I am getting an error.

Property 'utils' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/ethers")'.

```
setBalance(ethers.utils.formatUnits(balanceInWei, 'SAFEMOON'));
```

Comment: What version of ethers are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
 let ethers = require('./node_modules/ethers')
 ethers.utils.formatUnits(balanceInWei, 18)
```